# Is there any way to return a single image for every images call in a folder use Codeigniter?

Tags: image, codeigniter, redirect

I am working on a social media project where I have a huge amount of images which I don't want to move it to my beta development server.

For every profile picture I want to include from e.g images/profile folder I want php to return a single image e.g images/profile/nophoto.jpg as there is no photos for the profile pictures in this folder.

I have a helper class where I have a function profileicon() which will return me the profile images from the folder specified but that can't be used every where. In most cases I have used simply base_url and path to images.

```php
if(ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
 //some code to do the magic
}
```

I think we can do something in routes folder to do this magic or may be the uploads folder it self?

Thank you, all

Comment: First of all i didn't understand what are you trying to achieve? Secondly where is your code?

Comment: Let suppose you have a folder named "images" from where I am including all of the images for profile pictures, but on my testing server the images folder is empty so instead I want the system to return a single image (let say noimage.jpq) for all those images which are not existing in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've made different folders for different user. But you don't want to  show folders which are empty. Good practice is , You will have to check condition before showing image.

```
if(file_exist('path/'.$image)){
 //then show image .
}
```

You can also show a default image if image is not exist in database. I hope this will give an option to handle your several folders for users.

```
if(file_exist('path/'.$image)){
 //then show image .
}else{

  //show image
 }
```

Comment: This is how we can do when we are adding an image link but what if we already created lots of image links but images are not there for that links. So any way we can return to all these image links a single image (no photo) on our test server?

I am using a single folder for all the profile images.

Comment: Yes it is possible to catch images in a single array.